# Profiles property is deprecated is properties.yml for Spring-Kafka

Tags: java, intellij-idea, yaml, spring-kafka

[image]I'm configuring the application.yml file in my Spring Kafka MS
and I'm getting a notification that the profiles property is deprecated.
This 'profiles' property is deprecated

```
spring:
  profiles:
    active: docker
---
```

The suggested solution is to use this syntax:

```
spring:
  config:
    activate:
      on-profile: docker
---
```

But in the log, i can see that 'No active profile set:

I'm using Java 11 with Spring 2.6.2
IDEA: IntelliJ 2022.1 (Ultimate Edition)

```
 : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a false-positive deprecation warning. This will be fixed in 2022.1.1 version of IntelliJ IDEA. See [https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-291799/Spring-Boot:-false-positive-deprecation-mark-in-YAML-for-'spring](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-291799/Spring-Boot:-false-positive-deprecation-mark-in-YAML-for-%27spring)

Answer (score 1):

I think you are confusing `spring.profiles.active` (which is not deprecated https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/application-properties.html#application-properties.core.spring.profiles.active) with `spring.profiles` in a yaml document within the yaml file.

```yaml
spring:
  profiles:
    active: dev
---
spring:
  config:
    activate:
      on-profile: dev
  kafka:
    template:
      default-topic: devTopic
...
---
spring:
  config:
    activate:
      on-profile: prod
  kafka:
    template:
      default-topic: prodTopic
...
```

Vs.

```yaml
spring:
  profiles:
    active: local
---
spring:
  profiles: dev # deprecated
  kafka:
    template:
      default-topic: devTopic
...
---
spring:
  profiles: prod # deprecated
  kafka:
    template:
      default-topic: prodTopic
...
```

IntelliJ IDEA:

[image]

Comment: Hi Gary, in this image you can see that I'm getting a warning that this property is deprecated.

Comment: You should edit your question, not my answer. Perhaps a bug in your IDE? I added what IntelliJ shows; it also shows with a strikeout for me, until I added the `active` line.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the filename. Edit properties name to application. So,
properties.yml ->refactor->rename->application.yml